# How to plot multiple users' deviations from predictions of bandwidth consumption over time?

Tags: data-visualization

As it is said, a picture is worth 1000 words.  I have some data, and I need to put them in the right chart representation.

#### The working scenario is this:

some users have to predict how much internet bandwidth they will consume during 13 weeks. The users can form groups in order to buy more cheaper internet bandwidth. If they consume more than they said, they will have to pay more. Idea is to be as near is possible by what was predicted.

#### So, my data is like this:

```
user1 = {-0.075, -0.09, 0.32, -0.242, -0.368, -0.401, -0.73, -0.367, -0.294, -0.043, 1.296, 0.075, -0.373}  
user2 = {-0.009, -0.013, -0.01, -0.008, -0.008, -0.01, -0.005, -0.02, 0.287, 0.345, -0.104, -0.324, 0.144}   
user3 = {-0.197, -0.271, -0.153, -0.621, -0.549, -0.09, 1.745, 0.436, -0.271, 0.093, 0.085, 0.211, 0.331}  
user4 = {-0.005, -0.005, -0.006, -0.006, -0.006, -0.005, -0.006, -0.086, -0.171, -0.15, -0.175, -0.067, 0.078}  
user5 = {-0.223, -0.048, -0.129, 0.14, -0.535, -0.29, 0.51, 0.801, 0.521, 0.482, -0.105, 5.082, 5.516}  
group = {-0.509, -0.427, 0.022, -0.737, -1.466, -0.796, 1.514, 0.764, 0.072, 0.727, 0.997, 4.977, 5.696}
```

Negative values represents that user consumed less that what he predicted. Positive values means that user consumed more that he said. Values from the group array is the sum of the difference between what was predicted and what was consumed by each user.

#### Question:

Do you have any idea, about how can I represent those data in a chart in a easy to read way?

For example, as you can notice, difference between what was forecasted and what was consumed for user2 and user4 are very small, comparing to user2 and user5.

A CVS file with the previous data is [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/5VWY1z7q/Book_1.html).

Comment: I'd plot this using vioplot (in R), or box and whisker plots, with time along the x-axis.

Comment: What do you want to use the chart for?

Comment: @whuber: to easily identify the user which makes bad predictions. The positive deviations are more important than negative ones. Positives deviations means that user used more than he predicted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to plot this as the cumulated deviation from the predicted values. Whether this makes sense depends on what the billing/analysis period is: If the group has to stay below a certain limit for each quarter, this would allow them to see whether they're on track for reaching that goal. If their account balance is reset to zero every week, however, this kind of graph would be less useful.

[image]

Alternatively, an exceedance curve might be useful. This sorts each user's weekly deviations by magnitude. It allows to assess how much of the time each user was above or below their target. In the chart below, you can see that although all users apart from `user5` stayed below their limit more than 50% of the time, the group as a whole was above their limit almost 60% of the time.

[image]

And for a completely different way of showing the data, a [Waterfall Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart) could be interesting for you. It shows the breakdown of the weekly values, but with five variables it already becomes quite cluttered:

[image]

---

Here's the R code for the charts.

**Cumulative Deviation**

```
    library(ggplot2)

    data <- cumsum(
        data.frame(
            user1 = c(-0.075, -0.09, 0.32, -0.242, -0.368, -0.401, -0.73, -0.367, -0.294, -0.043, 1.296, 0.075, -0.373),  
            user2 = c(-0.009, -0.013, -0.01, -0.008, -0.008, -0.01, -0.005, -0.02, 0.287, 0.345, -0.104, -0.324, 0.144),   
            user3 = c(-0.197, -0.271, -0.153, -0.621, -0.549, -0.09, 1.745, 0.436, -0.271, 0.093, 0.085, 0.211, 0.331),
            user4 = c(-0.005, -0.005, -0.006, -0.006, -0.006, -0.005, -0.006, -0.086, -0.171, -0.15, -0.175, -0.067, 0.078),  
            user5 = c(-0.223, -0.048, -0.129, 0.14, -0.535, -0.29, 0.51, 0.801, 0.521, 0.482, -0.105, 5.082, 5.516),
            group = c(-0.509, -0.427, 0.022, -0.737, -1.466, -0.796, 1.514, 0.764, 0.072, 0.727, 0.997, 4.977, 5.696)
        )
    )

    data$week=c(1:13)

    molten <- melt(data,id.vars="week")

    p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x=week, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
            geom_line(aes(group=variable)) + 
            scale_colour_hue(h=c(100,250)) +
            geom_line(aes(y=molten$value[molten$variable=="group"]), colour="orange", size=1.5) +
            theme_bw() + opts(legend.position = "none") +
            geom_text(data=molten[molten$week==13,], aes(label=variable), colour="black", hjust=-0.2, size=4) +
            xlim(0,13.9) + xlab("Week") + ylab("Cumulated Deviation")
    print(p)
```

**Exceedance Curve**

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
        user1 = c(-0.075, -0.09, 0.32, -0.242, -0.368, -0.401, -0.73, -0.367, -0.294, -0.043, 1.296, 0.075, -0.373),  
        user2 = c(-0.009, -0.013, -0.01, -0.008, -0.008, -0.01, -0.005, -0.02, 0.287, 0.345, -0.104, -0.324, 0.144),   
        user3 = c(-0.197, -0.271, -0.153, -0.621, -0.549, -0.09, 1.745, 0.436, -0.271, 0.093, 0.085, 0.211, 0.331),
        user4 = c(-0.005, -0.005, -0.006, -0.006, -0.006, -0.005, -0.006, -0.086, -0.171, -0.15, -0.175, -0.067, 0.078),  
        user5 = c(-0.223, -0.048, -0.129, 0.14, -0.535, -0.29, 0.51, 0.801, 0.521, 0.482, -0.105, 5.082, 5.516),
        group = c(-0.509, -0.427, 0.022, -0.737, -1.466, -0.796, 1.514, 0.764, 0.072, 0.727, 0.997, 4.977, 5.696)
)

data_sorted <- data.frame(apply(data,2,sort,decreasing=T))
data_sorted$exceedance_prob=c(0:12)/12


molten <- melt(data_sorted,id.vars="exceedance_prob")

p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x=exceedance_prob, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
        geom_line(aes(group=variable)) + 
        scale_colour_hue(h=c(100,250)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=molten$value[molten$variable=="group"]), colour="orange", size=1.5) +
        theme_bw() + opts(legend.position = "none") +
        geom_text(data=molten[molten$exceedance_prob==0,], aes(label=variable), colour="black", hjust=1.2, size=4) +
        xlim(-0.1,1) + xlab("Exceedance Probability") + ylab("Deviation")
print(p)
```

**Exceedance Curve**

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
                user1 = c(-0.075, -0.09, 0.32, -0.242, -0.368, -0.401, -0.73, -0.367, -0.294, -0.043, 1.296, 0.075, -0.373),  
                user2 = c(-0.009, -0.013, -0.01, -0.008, -0.008, -0.01, -0.005, -0.02, 0.287, 0.345, -0.104, -0.324, 0.144),   
                user3 = c(-0.197, -0.271, -0.153, -0.621, -0.549, -0.09, 1.745, 0.436, -0.271, 0.093, 0.085, 0.211, 0.331),
                user4 = c(-0.005, -0.005, -0.006, -0.006, -0.006, -0.005, -0.006, -0.086, -0.171, -0.15, -0.175, -0.067, 0.078),  
                user5 = c(-0.223, -0.048, -0.129, 0.14, -0.535, -0.29, 0.51, 0.801, 0.521, 0.482, -0.105, 5.082, 5.516),
                group = c(-0.509, -0.427, 0.022, -0.737, -1.466, -0.796, 1.514, 0.764, 0.072, 0.727, 0.997, 4.977, 5.696)
        )

originaldata <- data
data <- data[,1:5]

lower<-as.data.frame(t(apply(data,1,"cumsum")))

data$week=c(1:13)
lower$week=c(1:13)


molten <- melt(data,id.vars="week")
moltenlower <- melt(lower,id.vars="week")
molten$lower <- moltenlower$value

p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x=week, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
        geom_rect(aes(
            xmin=week+as.numeric(variable)/6-0.5,
            xmax=week+as.numeric(variable)/6-0.35,
            ymin=lower,
            ymax=lower-value,
            group=variable),
            colour="black") +
        scale_fill_brewer()+
        theme_bw() + 
        xlim(0.5,13.5) + xlab("Week") + ylab("Cumulated Deviation") + ylim(-2,2)

print(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

For these particular data, I would make a line plot, like the following.

[image: line plot]

Here's the R code I used:

```
dat <- data.frame(user1 = c(-0.075, -0.09, 0.32, -0.242, -0.368, -0.401, -0.73, -0.367, -0.294, -0.043, 1.296, 0.075, -0.373),
                  user2 = c(-0.009, -0.013, -0.01, -0.008, -0.008, -0.01, -0.005, -0.02, 0.287, 0.345, -0.104, -0.324, 0.144),
                  user3 = c(-0.197, -0.271, -0.153, -0.621, -0.549, -0.09, 1.745, 0.436, -0.271, 0.093, 0.085, 0.211, 0.331),
                  user4 = c(-0.005, -0.005, -0.006, -0.006, -0.006, -0.005, -0.006, -0.086, -0.171, -0.15, -0.175, -0.067, 0.078),
                  user5 = c(-0.223, -0.048, -0.129, 0.14, -0.535, -0.29, 0.51, 0.801, 0.521, 0.482, -0.105, 5.082, 5.516))

plot(dat[,1], xlab="Time", ylab="Outcome", ylim=range(dat),
     type="l", lwd=2, xlim=c(1, nrow(dat)+2), las=1, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=seq(1, 13, by=2))
abline(h=0, lty=2, col="gray40")
col <- c("black", "blue", "red", "orange", "green")
for(i in 2:5)
  lines(dat[,i], col=col[i], lwd=2)
text(13.2, dat[13,]+c(0, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1, 0), paste("user", 1:5, sep=""), 
     col=col, adj=c(0, 0.5))
```